# NTP service is unable to connect to ntp.ubuntu.com on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ntp, systemd-timesyncd

I've been finding that my device recently has been unable to connect to **ntp.ubuntu.com** with its `systemd-timesyncd` service.

```
Mar 15 00:31:52 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 15 00:32:02 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 15 00:32:12 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 15 00:32:23 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Is **ntp.ubuntu.com** a viable NTP site to use for this or should I be using another NTP site?

Comment: I'm sure there are logs somewhere displaying errors, post them

Comment: Mar 15 00:31:52 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).                                                                 
Mar 15 00:32:02 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 15 00:32:12 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 15 00:32:23 l157 systemd-timesyncd[673]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Post them in your original question using the edit button and make sure you format it properly, use the help button if need be

Comment: Your log messages indicate that your system is unable to contact the Ubuntu NTP servers.  Millions of other systems can contact them successfully, so check that you don't have a firewall interfering.  It might be a firewall rule on your local system, or it might be a router further upstream, possibly even in your ISP if you're unlucky.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when connecting to the internet via eduroam. The problem goes away when connecting via another network. It seems that the eduroam administrators are just a bit too careful with their firewall configuration or something like that.

As long as you occasionally connect to a network other than eduroam it shouldn't be a problem and your time should always stay in sync.

Comment: I can confirm this happens to me. In my office network I can't sync, but I share my cellphone data with my laptop and, bang, it syncs immediately... thus suggesting is something with my ISP (or my router config but those I haven't touched in a while, so most likely my ISP). I have both 18.04 and 20.04 devices